# What do you call these market stalls that are inside of buildings?

Tags: word-request

https://youtu.be/o-s0qkBlxGM?t=478

Often, you see a stall inside of a building instead of being under a tent, what do you call these market stands. Is there a word for it?

Comment: That seems to be a link to a video game.  It doesn't show a real world place.  Is that the video you intended to post? If so, it's not very useful as an example.  Market stalls inside buildings are called "market stalls".  If it is a place in a building that sells stuff but isn't a market stall, then it is just a "shop".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JamesK. They are just "market stalls" and (at least in the UK) they would form part of a **covered market** such as the ones in Oxford and Gloucester. The other difference is that they are permanent stalls unlike the ones in an outdoor or open market which are owned by the stallholder, are portable and removed when the market closes. Most indoor stalls are rented and the physical stall passes to the next tennant when the business changes. Unlike the pitch, the rented space occupied by the temporary stall, of an outdoor or open market